# EF code first and many-to-many unique constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I have a many-to-many relationship as below:

```cs
public class ClassAClassB
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ClassAId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ClassBId { get; set; }
    public bool IsMain { get; set; }

    public virtual ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassB ClassB { get; set; }

}
```

Is possible using data annotations to create a unique constraint on 
ClassAId and IsMain == true?
ClassAId and IsMain == false as not to be unique

In SQL would be:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ClassAIsMain] ON [dbo].[ClassAClassB]
([ClassAId] ASC)
WHERE ([IsMain]=(1))
ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: [Require] don't work?

Comment: @BenRobinson, I added the SQL code I think would do the job